# Sum all attributes in a model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I was curious if there is an easy way to sum all attributes in a model without it looking repetitive, and not DRY.

I have a donation app, and this is how I summed everything:

```
def self.total_donations
    array = Category.pluck(
    'SUM(toilet_paper)',
    'SUM(dental_hygiene)',
    'SUM(first_aid)',
    'SUM(general_hygiene)',
    'SUM(underwear_socks)',
    'SUM(blankets)',
    'SUM(school_supplies)',
    'SUM(diapers)').flatten.compact
    array.inject(0){|sum, x| sum + x}
end
```

It's just ugly, but I don't know how to get around adding all of them up without doing something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one:

```
def self.total_donations
  sum("toilet_paper + dental_hygiene + first_aid + general_hygiene + underwear_socks + blankets + school_supplies + diapers")
end
```

The generated SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(toilet_paper + dental_hygiene + first_aid + general_hygiene + underwear_socks + blankets + school_supplies + diapers)
FROM "categories"
```

- short (no shorter possible)
- efficient (all the processing is done on the database layer)

Note, that in the class instance methods you don't have to use `Category`, because it is `self` (assuming, the method is in the `Category` model).

Comment: Thanks you Andrey.

Is it safe to say that, whatever the response, there isn't a way around writing out all the attributes of the model?

It seems like it's a must.

Comment: @TylerP3358 check out edited answer, it's even shorted and very efficient - all processing in database

Comment: How interesting... it returned zero? :D  I actually tried something similar back when I first wrote this.  No idea why it returned zero.  Looks beautiful, and correct!

Comment: @TylerP3358 it should work because it *is correct* :) . Test it by trying adding one column at a time. The sum should be increasing.

Comment: Hm, how interesting.  Tried going one at a time and the first one worked (toilet_paper), but adding the next column did not.

I'll mess around with it!

Comment: Just for fun I'll add that you could build the string dynamically and pass it into the summing method: `Category.columns.map(&:name).reject{ |attr|  %w(created_at updated_at).include?(attr)}.join(' + ')`

Comment: @TylerP3358 that's strange. What db and rails you use? with versions

Comment: @AndreyDeineko sqlite3 (this was for a project).  Rails 5.2

Comment: @TylerP3358 Okaay, supposed so. sqlite *might not* support this sum stuff. Sqlite is no fun. Check out their docs on something like this, sorry, never used it

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yeah, I am thinking it was Sqlite3.. it's a little goofy!

Thanks for the help though brother, the answer above still works fine.  Just not pretty :D